# How to get the parent protocol from within an iFrame using javascript?

Tags: javascript, iframe

I have two CDN domains, one that delivers content over https and the other one through http. And I'm creating a widget (inside an iframe) that could be used in a variety of domains and sometimes in secure pages and sometimes not.
Is there a way to infer using JavaScript the parent's protocol from within the widget's iFrame ?

Comment: you have access to top.location.href or parent.location.href from any iframe

Comment: also https will work for both, why don't stick with it?

Comment: @varela top.location.href won't work if the parent page is in another domain

Comment: @varela HTTPS usually has significantly longer TTFB due to longer connection times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out, if I ommit the protocol in the iframe of my widget then it will inherit the protocol of the parent, eg:

In my widget html:

```
<script>document.write("my protocol is " + document.location.protocol);</script>
```

The iframe code that points to my widget (to insert into the other sites):

```
<iframe src="//my-widget.example.com/widget"></iframe>
```

This requires my-wdiget.example.com/widget to work for both secure and unsecure connections (ie: http://my-widget.example.com/widget and https://my-widget.example.com/widget should both point to the same content) but that's OK because in my situation the only domains I don't have control over are the ones used as CDN.

Comment: what if your iframe was created using 'srcdoc' (HTML5) or dynamically using document.write or something.

Answer (score 0):

You can get informations from the main window just using:

```
window.parent.
```

Comment: This won't work if my iframe is being loaded on another domain.